# Swift: Radio buttons in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, radio-button

I'm creating app settings using `UICollectionView`. I know that `UITableView` is more suitable for static things like that but I need that customizability of collection view.

I have 2 sections and every section has 2 buttons. As button I use my custom XIB and for selected/unselected I use its functions. I've achieved it with this code but I don't feel like it's good code - if you know what I mean.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell00 = collectionView.cellForItem(at: [0,0]) as! RadioButtonCell
        let cell01 = collectionView.cellForItem(at: [0,1]) as! RadioButtonCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell00.selectCell()
            cell01.unselectCell()
        } else {
            cell00.unselectCell()
            cell01.selectCell()
        }
   } else {
        let cell10 = collectionView.cellForItem(at: [1,0]) as! RadioButtonCell
        let cell11 = collectionView.cellForItem(at: [1,1]) as! RadioButtonCell

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell10.selectCell()
            cell11.unselectCell()
        } else {
            cell10.unselectCell()
            cell11.selectCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Can it be done better? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    for i in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) {
         let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: [indexPath.section, i]) as! RadioButtonCell
         i == indexPath.row ? cell.selectCell() : cell.unselectCell()
    }
}
```